# java code for inserting image in mysql database

Tags: java

I'm trying to insert the image using java code,
I am able to insert the image but my table shows junk value
Here is my code,
Code for creating a table.

```
try {
    Connection con = null;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306 /Hotel",
           "root", "root");
      try {
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        String table = "CREATE TABLE ItemMenu(Image MEDIUMBLOB,
          Item_Codevarchar(20),Item_Name varchar(20),
          Item_Category varchar(20),Sub_Category varchar(20),
          Item_Rate varchar(20),Item_Kitchen varchar(20),
          Item_Division varchar(20),Item_Description varchar(20))";
      st.executeUpdate(table);
    } catch (SQLException s) {
        System.out.println("Table all ready exists!");
    }
    con.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Code for inserting the values into the table..

```
try {
    File f = new File(path);
    System.out.print(path);
    Connection con = null;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Hotel", "root", "root123");
```

//Here is the code for taking the values from the textfield and storing in string.

```
try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        System.out.println("hello how r u");
        String itemcode = itemcodefield.getText();
        String itemname = itemnamefield.getText();
        String categoryboxname = (String) categorybox.getSelectedItem();
        String subcategoryboxname = (String) subcategorybox.getSelectedItem();
        String rate = ratefield.getText();
        String kitchenboxname = (String) kitchenbox.getSelectedItem();
        String divisionboxname = (String) divisionbox.getSelectedItem();
        String description = descriptionfield.getText();
        String insert = "INSERT INTO ItemMenu(Image,Item_Code,
        Item_Name,Item_Category,Sub_Category,Item_Rate,Item_Kitchen,
        Item_Division,Item_Description)" 
        + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        System.out.println("am fyn");
```

//Here is the code for prepardstatemnt that is inserting that alues inside the mysql table.

```
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(insert);
        preparedStmt.setBinaryStream(1, (InputStream) f(int)
        (f.length()
        ));            
        preparedStmt.setString(2, itemcode);
        preparedStmt.setString(3, itemname);
        preparedStmt.setString(4, categoryboxname);
        preparedStmt.setString(5, subcategoryboxname);
        preparedStmt.setString(6, rate);
        preparedStmt.setString(7, kitchenboxname);
        preparedStmt.setString(8, divisionboxname);
        preparedStmt.setString(9, description);
        preparedStmt.execute();
    } catch (SQLException s) {
    }
    con.close();
} (Exception e1){
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: And what were expecting the database to show you?  The image?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/save_image.shtml), perhaps be useful

Comment: I hope you're not really logging into your database as root with the password "root".  (But at least you're using a prepared statement to avoid SQL injection!)

Comment: Unless it's just a typo in your example code, it looks like you are binding 'f' (the file) to the prepared statement (after casting it to an InputStream), when you should be using 'fis' (the FileInputStream).

Comment: Dear in that f i have given the path for the image...which im taking from the upload button and saved in the path..                i.e..       File f = new File(path);

Comment: @Wyzard...Yes dear am loging in in database and its inserting the image but its nt storing in blob its just showing me junk value dear..

Comment: @MadProgrammer ..I am able to insert the image into the database table but its storing as a junk..it must and should store as blob dear..soo what should i do ?any help...thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I dont know your application design but it is generally recommended that `instead of inserting images` into a DB, save the image to a folder and `insert path` to that folder in the DB.

Inserting image will be a performance issue. Inserting path will also reduce DB size and access to other resources will be fast.

Comment: Dear Imran do you have any other idea..i have to upload picture and evrytime when im uploading i have to take differents pictures..and that pictures(blob)should store in mysql db table..

Comment: @user1820472 Why, oh why, oh why do you have to store the image in the database? The only reason for doing that is highly clustered web-server setup and even than shared filesystem is a better approach. The need to have individual records for each upload does NOT stop you from leaving the uploaded file where it is (or copying it to another location) and storing the files URL (path) in your database. This way you will NOT need to read large object from the database server every time, your web server will be able to handle that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use FileInputStream object in second argument of setBinaryStream method. It will work.But save the image to a folder and insert path to that folder in the DB.its good way to handle upload image in the server side.

```
 PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(insert);
        preparedStmt.setBinaryStream(1, (InputStream)fis, (int)(f.length()));            
        preparedStmt.setString(2, itemcode);
        preparedStmt.setString(3, itemname);
        preparedStmt.setString(4, categoryboxname);
        preparedStmt.setString(5, subcategoryboxname);
        preparedStmt.setString(6, rate);
        preparedStmt.setString(7, kitchenboxname);
        preparedStmt.setString(8, divisionboxname);
        preparedStmt.setString(9, description);
        preparedStmt.execute();
    } catch (SQLException s) {
    }
    con.close();
} (Exception e1){
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I have try with this..Dear Its the same...im getting junk value instead of blob..

Comment: Dear its in 2nd argument...and its not working properly.

Comment: Refer this url: http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/jsp/jspinsertblob.html

Comment: have tried same code in java....its also storing junk value instead of blob.

Comment: then change the MEDIUMBLOB to LONGBLOB in DB and try.